# Did Lightroom move the color profiles?

Tags: lightroom

I thought that the profiles were somewhere around Basic?

[image: I thought it was above "Basic?"]

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember LR version with profiles in **Basic** panel. For current standalone (and I think also for CC) they are in **Camera Calibration**. Same for version 5

[image]

Comment: Didn't they move it in 7.3?

Comment: @Medajor have no idea. I own only standalone version. But based on the answer of Roberto seems to be.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that it was a bad install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the release of Lightroom-Classic v7.3 (April 2018) the Profile 'Chooser' is located in the Basic panel.
https://www.lightroomqueen.com/whats-new-in-lightroom-classic-73/
[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's where it was. It's just a bad install.